# Can't find `OBJROOT="$OBJROOT"` in the Cordova iOS package to attempt to fix Build Error: xcodebuild: Command failed with exit code 65

Tags: ios, database, cordova, compiler-errors, platform

I am trying to convert a game created through RPG Maker MV to an iOS build through Cordova in the Terminal. I have followed the tutorials perfectly, but the build fails with this Error:

error: unable to attach DB: error: accessing build database

database is locked Possibly there are two concurrent builds running in the same filesystem location.

xcodebuild: Command failed with exit code 65

I have looked through online search for help and I have found this post that seems to find the answer within the `OBJROOT="$OBJROOT/DependentBuilds"` Here is the link to this answer 
https://github.com/mattgallagher/CwlSignal/issues/24

Only issue is I am new to Cordova and converting iOS projects like this in general, so I have no idea where to find `OBJROOT="$OBJROOT` in the package to change it and see if that fixes my error.

I expect to be able to find that code line somewhere in the project and change it to `OBJROOT="$OBJROOT/DependentBuilds"` to fix the error. Unless anyone has an updated answer that will work, since this one may cause other compiler issues as it says in the post link above.

Answer (score 0):

Well I got it to work... Unfortunately all I did was totally deleted all my packaging and re-exported the RPG Maker MV game and started over.

Sometimes it just takes a re-start I guess.

-Brantley